# Why command is not executed inside the project's folder?

Tags: go, cron, sh

I am trying to execute the command using the `sh` file as given below:

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "executing......................................"
wget -i http://example.com -O /dev/null
```

Which is running properly when I am accessing directly from my desktop folder.

But when I integrate it with my golang project for example: 
I created a folder named `myProject/sh` and pasted the file there.

Now using cron in my another package I am trying to access the `test.sh` file.

```
func RunCron() {
    c := cron.New()
    c.AddFunc("10 * * * * *", ExecuteFunction)
    c.Start()
}

func ExecuteFunction(){
    fmt.Println("test----------------")
    utils.ExecuteCommand("sh "+config.GetBasePath()+"sh/test.sh")
}
```

Now it outputs something like

```
test----------------
Result: executing......................................

exit status 4: --2018-01-16 18:25:10--  http://example.com
Resolving http://example.com)... 1.1.1.1
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|2.2.2.2|:8080... failed: Connection refused.
No URLs found in example.com.
```

I am unable to figure out that why the same code runs well in my desktop folder but stops executing inside my project's folder. Can you please save my time by telling me whats wrong am I doing?

Thanks!

Comment: It is executing, it's just exiting with a non-zero code because you're trying to read the list of URLs to get from a file named `http://example.com`. The output clearly tells you: `No URLS found in example.com`.

Comment: But when I access the same code out of the project it displays `/dev/null                           100%[==================================================================>]      60  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2018-01-16 18:32:08 (4.31 MB/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [60/60]
`

Comment: file contains `#!/bin/bash  
echo "executing......................................"
wget -i http://example.com:8080/api/v1/test-shfile -O /dev/null`

Comment: It seems like a problem connecting to whatever host you pass. Are you running the script and your program on the same machine? Is the host a plain string, or are you by chance using environment variables? Does it require any credentials?

Answer (score -1):

have you considered using `"os/exec"`

`cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", test.sh)`

edit : a'right,, i didnt sugesting then, ,i test it myself. .

```
func main() {
        cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "test.sh")
        out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("output is :\n%s\n", string(out)) }
```

Comment: Suggestions belong in comments, not in answers.

Comment: This still does not answer OP's question. The problem is reaching `http://example.com/...` within the script, not running the actual script.

Comment: ohh jezz.. i didnt even see that. . whooops.. my bad. .i didnt quiet get it tho. .